# Search string in Array<AnyObject> with case insensitive

Tags: arrays, swift, swift2

I have application that stores string values from server. Then I am using SearchView for write string that can be in List. It must be case insensitive. So far I have this. But this is not the magic i am looking for.

```
if (myListTags as NSArray).containsObject(searchBar.text!) {
            print("FOUND")
            getCategoryPick()
}
```

I tried to join it with `caseInsensitiveCompare` but i failed. Any help for me?
It would be perfect if that code can understand letter similarity in czech language .. (č = c, ž = z, í = i ......)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"č" is the Unicode character "LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CARON".
It can be decomposed into "c" + "ˇ" where the latter (the "CARON") is a so-called "diacritical mark".

To ignore diacritical marks when comparing strings (so that
"č" = "c"), use the `.DiacriticInsensitiveSearch` option:

```
let list = ["č", "ž"]
let search = "C"

if (list.contains {
    $0.compare(search, options: [.DiacriticInsensitiveSearch, .CaseInsensitiveSearch]) == .OrderedSame
    }) {
        print("Found")
}
```

Or, if you want to find matching substrings:

```
if (list.contains {
    $0.rangeOfString(search, options: [.DiacriticInsensitiveSearch, .CaseInsensitiveSearch]) != nil
    }) {
        print("Found")
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the correct answer. :-) have a nice day

Comment: One more questing...how can i retrieve value or ID of searched item in list?

Comment: @PanMluvčí: You can use `indexOf()` instead of `contains()`. That returns the index of the first matching item.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:):

```
if myListTags.contains({(($0 as? NSString)?.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(searchBar.text!) ?? .OrderedAscending) == .OrderedSame }) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply...yes now it can read "cestina" or "CEsTINa" as same...but it can't "Čeština...is there something to make this line even better?"